# Converting Image-Based PDF to Text-Based PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to convert Image-Based PDF to Text-Based PDF. There are lot of tools available for using. But iam looking for a C# code to make an application. I heard about Tessara but i not get code for C#. it is available only c/c++.

I used MODI dll to convert Image to Text. The process is Converting Each page of PDF to Image(using Acrobat dll) and with that output Image(bmp/tif) we can use MODI to get text. is there any possibility available to change the MODI object to PDF?

```
MODI.Document doc = new MODI.Document();
doc.Create(ImagePath);
doc.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, false, false);
doc.SaveAs("c://.../test.pdf", MODI.MiFILE_FORMAT.miFILE_FORMAT_DEFAULTVALUE, MODI.MiCOMP_LEVEL.miCOMP_LEVEL_HIGH);
//But this line creating PDF but the PDF is not opened. Due to error.
```

if u have any other way to do this please let me know.

Regards,
R.Balajiprasad

Comment: don't you have to use OCR to read from an image? why not search in that way, try to find some OCR .net component depending on your needs.

Comment: @abmv: Did you even read his question? What does `doc.OCR` look like if not *OCR*?

Comment: oops! the code was not formatted, will now it is ...

Comment: i have found some 3rd party tools to use in C# but all need license. For Ex, Acqua Forest, Wise Trends, Lead Tools etc. is it possible to accomblish using any Acrobat dlls???

Answer (score 0):

You can use google's [Tesseract-OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) and the documentation can be found [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/). It's free and works perfectly. There is a nugget package ([IronOcr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronOcr/2022.1.0)) which uses tesseract and it can be found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronOcr/2022.1.0).